# Need to output text from extension

Tags: visualforce, controller, outputtext

is it possible to output text like this?

Controller:

```
public string ywc1{get;set;}
public string ywc2{get;set;}
public string ywc3{get;set;}

for (Bank_Application__c data: [SELECT Experian1__c, Transunion1__c, equifax1__c 
    FROM Bank_Application__c where 
    Lead_Id__c = : leadid Order By id ASC]) {
    if (data.Experian1__c = true) {
        ywc1 += '<li>' + 'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>' + 'Experian 888-397-3742.';
    } else if (data.Equifax1__c = true) {
        ywc2 += '<li>' + 'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>' + 'Equifax 601-502-0198. ';
    } else if (data.Transunion1__c = true) {
        ywc3 += '<li>' + 'Removal of Fraud Alerts with all Credit Bureaus. Please contact:<br/>' + ' Transunion 877-322-8228.';
    }
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!ywc1}" escape="false" /> 
<apex:outputText value="{!ywc2}" escape="false" /> 
<apex:outputText value="{!ywc3}" escape="false" />
```

This should be text in document.

Comment: Its hard to know what is not working, maybe you can update your post with additional information.

Comment: @RahulSharma, i have trivial problem, need to show text in visualforce from custom extension controller when checkbox is checked and that's it...